# iOS Nav. Bar Image

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem, appdelegate

iOS Nav. Bar Image

I need to display a Image in the nav. bar, but only on the first screen of the App., then the rest are all blank. Problem is if I set the background to a image it carries over to all other screens. How can I have it on the main screen nav. bar, but change it back to blank on all the others?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`UIAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)'s **`appearanceWhenContainedIn`** method to specify classes that cause modification to occur.

Clear the image in all navigation bars:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Set an image in a navigation bar in `YourViewController`:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[YourViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Can get more information on were to put the second line of code?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `titleView` of the `navigationItem` inside the ViewController, wich should display the image on the `UINavigationBar`.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBarItem"]];
```

Comment: I need it to take up the whole nav. bar not just the center, or display two images in the nav. bar side by side in button and be able to resize them or something.